# Perl code causing spaces in PDF report

Tags: oracle, perl, pdf

I am working on an issue which involves some perl code stored in an Oracle table. I have a PDF report which is displaying certain text with extra spaces in them i.e. "L I K E  T H I S". Below is the subroutine from where I believe the problem is coming from:

Inside a for loop a subroutine is being called as such:

`printAdjustedFieldEW(238, $LINE_POS, uc($RECS->[$i]{'EVENT_WHERE'}), 35);`

Here is the subroutine:

```
 sub printAdjustedFieldEW {
  my ($left_pos, $line_height, $case_field, $allowed, $align) = @_;
  my ($field_str, $line_pos) = ('', 0);

  if($case_field =~ /(.*?)\\+$/) {
    $case_field = $1;
  }

  my @field = split //, $case_field;

  if($allowed == 0 || ((1.5*length($case_field)) - 1 <= $allowed)) {
    prText($left_pos, $line_height, $case_field, $align);
  }
  else {
    for $cnt (0 .. $#field) {
      $field_str .= $field[$cnt];

      if($cnt != (scalar @field - 1)) {
        $line_pos = (rindex($field_str, "\n") > 0) ? rindex($field_str, "\n") : 0;

        $field_str .= (1.5*(length(substr($field_str, $line_pos)) + length($field[$cnt+1])) < $allowed) ? ' ' : "\n";
      }
    }

    @field = split("\n", $field_str);

    for $pos (0 .. $#field) {
      prText($left_pos, $line_height + (4*(scalar @field - ($pos+1))), $field[$pos], $align);
    }
  }
}
```

Is there anything here which seems to be padding spaces between letters and could be fixed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm thinking the problem is a discrepancy related to characterset, but I'm no Perl expert either....What characterset does tyour database use?  AL32UTF8?  Something else?  What characherset have you chosen in Perl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line splits `$case_field` by character:

```
my @field = split //, $case_field;
```

And the following line adds a space after each character as long as the condition is true:

```
$field_str .= (1.5*(length(substr($field_str, $line_pos)) + length($field[$cnt+1])) < $allowed) ? ' ' : "\n";
```

Removing the space from the `?` operator solved the problem:

```
$field_str .= (1.5*(length(substr($field_str, $line_pos)) + length($field[$cnt+1])) < $allowed) ? '' : "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your subroutine has an `if` conditional.  The true branch just prints out the string in one go using `prText()`.  The `else` branch calls `prText()` once for each character and calculates the position for each character.  The calculations seem to be based on the number of characters which is odd (given that a character like 'W' would usually require more space than a character like 'l'.

The PDF::Reuse module (which I'm guessing is what you're using) provides a [prStrWidth](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::Reuse#prStrWidth---calculate-the-string-width) function for determining how much horizontal space a string will require on the page in the currently selected font.  I recommend replacing the contents of the `else` block with code that uses that function.